# Excel sum range of cells in column where row value meets requirement

Tags: excel, range, cells, formulas

Below I have a column of numbers (particle size), which is in order from maximum to minimum. I'd like to sum the column to the right (mass retained), but only from the highest particle size to a specific particle size.

[image: Columns]

Example:
I would like to sum the values in Mass Retained where the Particle Size is greater than 20mm.

How can I select the mass retained meeting this requirement?

Thanks

Comment: like `=SUMIF(A:A,">20",B:B)` ??? (which would be 0 in your case) ...to not exclude the 20mm itself `=SUMIF(A:A,">=20",B:B)` should be what you want

Comment: @DirkReichel That's exactly what I'm looking for - thanks! I found [link](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-indexmatch-as-a-cell-reference/) but your method is cleaner.